# Animation is disturbed by Multitasking

Tags: ios, multitasking

I am developing an iPhone applciation in which I am applying UIView Animation, but when multitasking occurs like user answers a call or a skype call, my animation is disturbed.

Is there any way to avoid this?

**EDIT**
Suppose a scenario Skype call is running, in the meanwhile i started my application that has some UIView Animation, while skype call is running its behaviour turns strange? Any comment on that ??

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid disturbance from incoming calls and other things like that. What you **can** do is to save the state of you animation in the moment when interruption happens and restore this exact state to continue your animation when app is back in foreground.

Comment: Suppose the scenario Skype call is running, in the meanwhile i started my application that has some UIView Animation, while skype call is running its behaviour turns strange? Any comment on that ??

Answer (score 0):

What usually happens is that the animation jumps to the "end point" instantly. In case you have cascading animations it's best to make sure you are not in multitasking when starting the new one.